# typeahead in angular js not working

Tags: angularjs, typeahead.js, angular-ui-typeahead

I am working in a project where i have to retrieve details from mongod and show it as a type ahead in a text box .

My code is

Html :

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="resourceName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Enter the Page Name<span>*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" ng-model="selected" typeahead="getPageName()" required>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.getPageName = function(){
                return $http.get('/api/getPageName').success(function(response){
                    return limitToFilter(response.data, 15);
                }).error(function(response){

                });
            };
```

But the problem is that , the function is not at all getting called if i type in the textbox .

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, what are you using for your typeahead? Why is your question tagged with both typeahead.js and angular-ui-typeahead? Your markup certainly doesn't look like the one you would use with angular-ui-typeahead: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-change directive to call function after you start typing.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" ng-model="selected" ng-change="getPageName()" required>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange